# Is it possible to use a jQuery datepicker with an `onchange` event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, symfony

I have a page that queries the database and returns all invoices between two dates. The controller provides defaults if none are provided, however I can't work out how to get an `onchange` event to generate a new route to load.

**Controller:**

The query to correctly returning the records between `$min` and `$max`

```
/** *********************************************************************************************
* @Route("/invoices/view/monthly/{min}/{max}"  ,name="view_monthly_invoices", defaults={"min"="2016-01-01", "max"="now"})
********************************************************************************************** */
public function viewMonthlyInvoicesAction(Request $request, \DateTime $min, \DateTime $max)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$invoicesinrange = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Invoice')->invoicesWithinDates($min, $max);

return $this->render('invoices/view.daterange.invoices.html.twig', array(
    'invoicesinrange' => $invoicesinrange,
    'min'=>$min->format('Y-m-d'),
    'max'=>$max->format('Y-m-d'),
));
}
```

**HTML:**

This is the html in the DOM I'm trying to work with

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="invoice_invoicedate" class="required">Minimum Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="min_date" name="invoice[mindate]" required="required" class="datepicker" value="16-Jan-2016" />

    <label for="invoice_invoicedate" class="required">Maximum Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="max_date" name="invoice[maxdate]" required="required" class="datepicker" value="17-Jan-2016" />
</div>
```

**script in question:**

This is what I've been tying myself up knots with. Is there a way for it to identify which field has been `change`d and then update the route to load correctly?

```
$('#min_date, #max_date').on('change', function () {
    var date = $(this).val(); 
    if (date) { 
        window.location = '/invoices/view/monthly/' . date . '/' . otherdate; 
    }
    return false;
});
```

...In case it's of relevance, I also have this jQuery UI script which is used across several pages:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        changeYear: true,
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `is()` to figure out which one is acted on and to assign url variables accordingly

```
// store elemnts in collection to make it easy to get the other one when changed
var $datePickers = $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : "dd-M-yy",
    changeYear : true,
}).on('change', function () {
    var $el = $(this),
            // simple filter to get other input
            $otherInput = $datePickers.not(this),
            // boolean based on which was changed
            isMinDate = $el.is('#min_date'),
            // ternaries to assign vaariables
            date = isMinDate ? $el.val() : $otherInput.val(),
            otherdate = isMinDate ? $otherInput.val() : $el.val();
    // make sure both dates exist - should be validated more
    if (date && otherdate) {
        window.location = '/invoices/view/monthly/' + date + '/' + otherdate;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That works 'straight out the box' thank you very much @charlietfl - I'll be sure to go through it to know for the next time :)